# Problems with CD gitlab jobs when deploying

Tags: gitlab-ci

I'm trying to set up ad CD jobs to deploy in live production when master change and deploy in staging when staging branch changes.

My `.gitlab-ci.yml` is as follows

```
before_script:
    - apt-get update -qq
    - apt-get install -qq git
    # Setup SSH deploy keys
    - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get install -qq openssh-client )'
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" &gt; ~/.ssh/config'

deploy_live:
    type: deploy
    environment:
        name: Live
        url: xxxxx.xxxxx
    script:
        - ssh xxxx@0.0.0.0 -p 11111 "cd /www/xxx/public && git checkout master && git pull origin master && exit"
    only:
        - master

deploy_staging:
    type: deploy
    environment:
        name: staging
        url: staging.xxxx.xxxx
    script:
        - ssh xxx@0.0.0.0 -p 11111 "cd /www/xxx/public && git checkout staging && git pull origin staging && exit"
    only:
        - staging
```

I changed some connection  data

When i change something, and job is thrown in pipeline i get this:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 14.0.0-rc1 (19d2d239)
  on docker-auto-scale ed2dce3a
  feature flags: FF_SKIP_DOCKER_MACHINE_PROVISION_ON_CREATION_FAILURE:true
Resolving secrets
00:00
Preparing the "docker+machine" executor
00:35
Using Docker executor with image ruby:2.5 ...
Pulling docker image ruby:2.5 ...
Using docker image sha256:13fd310aa3adfd5db7b986cc64b5b6816bea774cf51de468d917e6ef038b418f for ruby:2.5 with digest ruby@sha256:d273723056dda84bda81454eb42743c6c29fdf2c2d4d42bddf8e3dca8bb99aa4 ...
Preparing environment
00:02
Running on runner-ed2dce3a-project-27561610-concurrent-0 via runner-ed2dce3a-srm-1624167534-5f218231...
Getting source from Git repository
00:13
$ eval "$CI_PRE_CLONE_SCRIPT"
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/rankia/portugal/.git/
Created fresh repository.
Checking out 086ab265 as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:05
Using docker image sha256:13fd310aa3adfd5db7b986cc64b5b6816bea774cf51de468d917e6ef038b418f for ruby:2.5 with digest ruby@sha256:d273723056dda84bda81454eb42743c6c29fdf2c2d4d42bddf8e3dca8bb99aa4 ...
$ apt-get update -qq
$ apt-get install -qq git
$ which ssh-agent || ( apt-get install -qq openssh-client )
/usr/bin/ssh-agent
$ eval $(ssh-agent -s)
Agent pid 266
$ ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
Identity added: /dev/fd/63 (ansible-generated on QtF-rankia)
$ mkdir -p ~/.ssh
$ [[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" &gt; ~/.ssh/config
/bin/bash: line 133: gt: command not found
Cleaning up file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The is no such command `&gt;`. It looks like HTML escaping of the redirection operation (`>`). I'm guessing you copied this line from some online resource, and something got mangled on the way.

To make a long story short, replace the `&gt` with a `>` and you should be OK:

```
- '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
```